# spring 3 autowiring and junit testing

Tags: spring, junit, autowired

My code:

```
@Component
public class A {
    @Autowired
    private B b;

    public void method() {}
}

public interface X {...}

@Component
public class B implements X {
    ...
}
```

I want to test in isolation class A. Do I have to mock class B? If yes, how? Because it is autowired and there is no setter where i could send the mocked object.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

> I want to test in isolation class A.

You should absolutely mock B, rather than instantiate and inject an instance of B.  The point is to test A whether or not B works, so you should not allow a potentially broken B interfere with the testing of A.

That said, I highly recommend [Mockito](http://mockito.org/).  As mocking frameworks go, it is extremely easy to use.  You would write something like the following:

```
@Test
public void testA() {
    A a = new A();
    B b = Mockito.mock(B.class); // create a mock of B
    Mockito.when(b.getMeaningOfLife()).thenReturn(42); // define mocked behavior of b
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(a, "b", b); // inject b into the B attribute of A

    a.method();

    // call whatever asserts you need here
}
```

Comment: With the new version of Mockito, I'd use the `@InjectMocks` annotation on the declaration of `A` and get rid of the reflection `setField(..)`

Comment: But a is a bean, i.e. a proxy (created with AOP). This will not succeed. I have tried something similar and the error was that field b could not be found on A (because it is a proxy).

Comment: i understand the wanting to test of isolation of class A but why would B absolutely have to be mocked? there's no way you can have A work if B is broken.

Comment: @dtc That's a good point.  My views on mock objects have evolved since I answered this question, and these days I would instead find a way to decouple A from B in the first place.

Answer (score 18):

Here's an example of how I got my tests working with Spring 3.1, JUnit 4.7, and Mockito 1.9:

*FooService.java*

```
public class FooService {
    @Autowired private FooDAO fooDAO;
    public Foo find(Long id) {
        return fooDAO.findById(id);
    }
}
```

*FooDAO.java*

```
public class FooDAO {
    public Foo findById(Long id) {
        /* implementation */
    }
}
```

*FooServiceTest.java*

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FooServiceTest {
    @Mock private FooDAO mockFooDAO;
    @InjectMocks private FooService fooService = new FooService();

    @Test public final void findAll() {
        Foo foo = new Foo(1L);
        when(mockFooDAO.findById(foo.getId()).thenReturn(foo);

        Foo found = fooService.findById(foo.getId());
        assertEquals(foo, found);
    }
}
```

Comment: If not using `MockitoJUnitRunner`, important to remember in `FooServiceTest`:  `@Before
 public void initMocks() {
  MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
 }`

Answer (score 15):

You can inject the field via reflection using Spring's `ReflectionTestUtils.setField` (or the junit extension `PrivateAccessor`) or you can create a mock application context and load that. Though for a simple unit (non-integration) test, I favor using reflection for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

[This forum discussion](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=92725) makes sense to me. You can declare your private member b as a type of InterfaceB which is implemented by the class B (ie: service-oriented) then declare a MockB class would also implement the same interface. In your test environment application context, you declare MockB class and your production application context you declare the normal B class and in either case, the code for class A does not need to be changed since it will be auto-wired.

Comment: With @Autowire you don't declare your beans in application context, they're just here in the classpath. So, this solution doesn't work.

Comment: This solution works if you wire the bean byType (in 2.5) or declare a qualifier (3.0). In Spring 2.5 you can autowire to a bean declared in your XML Application Context configuration as can be read in documentation http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-autowire. In Spring 3.0 they still allow you to do this with the @Qualifier annotation (documented at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation).