# Injecting mock @Service for Spring unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring, spring-mvc, mockito

I am testing a class that uses use @Autowired to inject a service:

```
public class RuleIdValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidRuleId, String> {

    @Autowired
    private RuleStore ruleStore;

    // Some other methods
}
```

But how can I mock ruleStore during testing? I can't figure out how to inject my mock RuleStore into Spring and into the Auto-wiring system.

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is quite easy with [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/):

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class RuleIdValidatorTest {
    @Mock
    private RuleStore ruleStoreMock;

    @InjectMocks
    private RuleIdValidator ruleIdValidator;

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        when(ruleStoreMock.doSomething("arg")).thenReturn("result");

        String actual = ruleIdValidator.doSomeThatDelegatesToRuleStore();

        assertEquals("result", actual);
    }
}
```

Read more about [@InjectMocks](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.23.0/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) in the Mockito javadoc or in a [blog post](http://www.jayway.com/2012/02/25/mockito-and-dependency-injection/) that I wrote about the topic some time ago.

Available as of Mockito 1.8.3, enhanced in 1.9.0.

Answer (score 10):

You can use something like Mockito to mock the rulestore returned during testing.  This Stackoverflow post has a good example of doing this:

[spring 3 autowiring and junit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660933/spring-3-autowiring-and-junit-testing)

Comment: Thanks, I missed that one.

        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(validator, "ruleStore", ruleStore);

Answer (score 2):

You can do following:

```
package com.mycompany;    

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@DependsOn("ruleStore")
public class RuleIdValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidRuleId, String> {

    @Autowired
    private RuleStore ruleStore;

    // Some other methods
}
```

And your Spring Context should looks like:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany" />

<bean id="ruleStore" class="org.easymock.EasyMock" factory-method="createMock">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="com.mycompany.RuleStore"/>
</bean>
```