# Spring autowiring fails when using ConstraintValidator(calling a REST Service) in Junit test case

Tags: spring, rest, junit, autowired, custom-validators

Am validating countrycode using Constraintvalidator which inturn calls a Rest Service.
   CountryCodeValueValidator:

```
public class CountryCodeValueValidator
    implements ConstraintValidator<CountryCodeValidator, Object> {

@Override
public void initialize(CountryCodeValidator countryCodeValidator) {

}

@Autowired
private CountryCodeClient countryCodeClient;

public void setCountryCodeClient(CountryCodeClient countryCodeClient) {
    this.countryCodeClient = countryCodeClient;
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(Object countryCode,
        ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {

    if (countryCode == null) {
        return true;
    }
    String country = (String) countryCode;

    return countryCodeClient
            .getCountry(country)
            .getStatusCode()
            .is2xxSuccessful();
}
```

}

CountryCodeValidator:
     @Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE)
     @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
     @Constraint(validatedBy = CountryCodeValueValidator.class)
     @Documented

```
 public @interface CountryCodeValidator {

String message() default "{people.address_invalid_country}";

Class<?>[] groups() default {};

Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented @interface List {
    CountryCodeValidator[] value();
}
```

Test Case:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

@Category(Small.class)
public class CountryValidationTest {

```
ValidatorFactory validatorFactory;

@Mock
CountryCodeClient countryCodeClient;

@InjectMocks
CountryCodeValueValidator countryCodeValueValidator;


@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    //countryCodeClient = mock(CountryCodeClient.class);

    validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();

}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    validatorFactory.close();
}



@Test
public void test() throws Exception {

    Country country = new CountryBuilder().setCode("ABC3173EF24").createCountry();

    Validator validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();

      Mockito.when(countryCodeClient.getCountry("USA")).thenReturn(ok().build()); 
    assertMessage(
        "country_code_invalid",
        validator.validate(country)
    );

}
```

It is throwing NullpointerException.

I found following links. but i didn't get how to use them
[spring 3 autowiring and junit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660933/spring-3-autowiring-and-junit-testing)

My situation is something similar
[How to autowire service in ConstraintValidator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338883/how-to-autowire-service-in-constraintvalidator)

Comment: And why shouldn't it throw a nullpointer? You create a mock, inject dependencies and next you are completly ignoring it. You are using the validator factory to create a new validator. Just use the instance created in your test. (You should create it there). However generally injection in JSR310 validators fails because those validators aren't spring managed. So even if your test would work. it would probably fail at runtime.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum. "Just use the instance created in your test. (You should create it there)." means i need to create a new validator instance and use it across. It is still a nightmare to me. Please help me out.

Comment: What is so hard about it... Create a new instance. `new CountryCodeValueValidator()` for the field that has `@InjectMocks` onto it (or it might even already be in initialized due to that annotation and use that instance).

Comment: Thanks!! @M.Deinum. As we already have `@InjectMocks` no need to create the instance.                 `when(countryCodeValueValidator.isValid(country.getCode(), context)).thenReturn(true);` I used like this. it is still throwing NPE

Comment: Your`countryCodeValueValidator` isn't a mock so what you wrote in y9our comment won't even work.